# Length of a string for a data validation list

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble with a data validation list. I'm using vba to generate the list from a database(another page of the workbook).

The string, which contains the list, can be greater than 255 char.

When the string is greater than 255 char, then I close the file, then I try to reopen the file, it says  and suppresses all the data validation lists in the workbook.

Is there a way to work around this error?

Here is the code I am using:

```
For iter4 = 2 To nbWsheet

            If Wsheet.Cells(iter4, 2) = Cat And Wsheet.Cells(iter4, ColMod) = "x" And Wsheet.Cells(iter4, ColStd) = "oui" Then

                TableValue = Wsheet.Cells(iter4, 4).Value & " - " & Wsheet.Cells(iter4, 7).Value
                TableValue = Replace(TableValue, ",", Chr(130)) 'Remplace la virgule par le symbole alt0130
                Table = Table & "," & TableValue 'Création de la liste

            End If

        Next iter4

        'Ajout de la list
        With Cells(iGlob, 5).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=Table
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = ""
            .ShowError = ""
        End With
```

Any help is appreciated.

note : this code generates many data validation lists

Comment: This might help http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

To make it work, i generated a list in a hidden sheet. All of my lists are in column A. To know witch list goes where, i made a iteration calculation for each list. When the list is generated it know where it start and where it end in the column A

Here is the code i use

```
            For iter4 = 2 To nbWsheet

            If Wsheet.Cells(iter4, 2) = Cat And Wsheet.Cells(iter4, ColMod) = "x" And Wsheet.Cells(iter4, ColStd) = "oui" Then

                TableValue = Wsheet.Cells(iter4, 4).Value & " - " & Wsheet.Cells(iter4, 7).Value
                TableValue = Replace(TableValue, ",", Chr(130)) 'Remplace la virgule par le symbole alt0130
                Sheets("hidden").Cells(iterRow, 1).Value = TableValue
                iterRow = iterRow + 1
                rowCat = rowCat + 1

            End If

        Next iter4

        'Calcul du nombre de ligne dans la feuille hidden pour avoir la bonne information dans chaque liste
        rowCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("hidden").Columns(1))
        rowDebut = rowCount - rowCat + 1
        'Ajout de la liste
        With Cells(iGlob, 5).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=hidden!A" & rowDebut & ":A" & rowCount
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            '.InputTitle = ""
            '.ErrorTitle = ""
            '.InputMessage = ""
            '.ErrorMessage = ""
            '.ShowInput = ""
            '.ShowError = ""
        End With
        iGlob = iGlob + 1
        rowCat = 0
    End If
```